# ituneconnect: Miss 3.5 inch screenshot

Tags: ios, iphone, publishing

My app is camera based app for iPhone5/iPhone5s. When I distributed it in iTuneConnect, it requires 3.5 inch screenshot. But I don't have iPhone4/iPhone4s, and simulator cannot mock camera.

Any method to disable the 3.5 inch iPhone support to avoid the screenshot uploading?

Comment: Just create in Photoshop or Gimp a 320x480 document and paste the screenshots from the iPhone 5. Would be the esiest solution in my opinion

Comment: Thanks. If there is no certain settings in Xcode5 or ituneconnection, Photoshop or gimp is the last step. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run your app on the 4inch screen device and when the camera is in use, take a screen shot and save the picture. Then add this picture to Xcode. Load this picture into a full screen UIImageView and display it, then run the iPhone 3.5inch simulator. In the simulator it will look like the camera is working (even though it's just a picture), then take the screenshot from within the simulator and there you go.

Hope this helps

Comment: Lol,good idea. I just wanna confirm I didn't miss any configuration on Xcode5.1. Thanks for your suggestion.